# $_post retorna vazio, tentei de tudo, pessoal. Por gentileza, me ajuda

Tags: php, javascript, html

Eu tenho esse problema e não consigo resolver, o form está correto mas quando o usuário clica no botão salvar, o arquivo salvar.php é acionado normalmente, mas perde o conteúdo do $_POST....Me ajudem!

arquivo index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt" class="no-js">    
<body>
    <div>
        <div>
            <form action="salvar.php" method="post">
                <div class="row">                
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="name">Id</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="id" value=""> 
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="name">Código</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="codigo" value=""> 
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="name">Descrição</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="descricao" value=""> 
                    </div>
                </div> 
            </form>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button type="submit" onclick="salvar()">Salvar</button>
            <button type="button" onclick="fechar()">Cancelar</button>
        </div> 
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function salvar() {
            window.location.href = "salvar.php";
        }
    </script>  
</body>
</html>
```

No arquivo salvar.php eu leio a variavel $_post e o valor é vazio, como mostro no arquivo em anexo.

arquivo salvar.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt" class="no-js">    
    <body>
        <?php 
            var_dump($_POST);
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Resultado:

**C:\wamp\www\salvar.php:5:
array (size=0)
  empty**

Eu não consigo resolver e já perdi o domingo inteiro.
Não troquei de versão de nada, nenhuma atualização.
Boa semana a todos e obrigado por dispensar seu tempo.

Comment: Vc quer usar Ajax pra isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do jeito que está fazendo é como se estivesse redirecionando para o salvar.php, o ideal seria usar o ajax para recuperar esses dados, ou usando o jquery ou qualquer outro cliente http, como o axios por exemplo.

Tente fazer algo assim, não esquecendo de chamar o jquery.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="pt" class="no-js">    
    <body>
        <div>
            <div>
                <form action="salvar.php" id="form_exemplo">
                    <div class="row">                
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="name">Id</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="id" value=""> 
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="name">Código</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="codigo" value=""> 
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="name">Descrição</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="descricao" value=""> 
                        </div>
                    </div> 
                </form>
            </div>
            <div>
                <button id="btn_salvar">Salvar</button>
                <button type="button">Cancelar</button>
            </div> 
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready({
               $('#btn_salvar').on('click', function(event){
                    event.preventDefault();

                    $.ajax({
                        url:'salvar.php',
                        type:'post',
                        data:$('#form_exemplo').serialize(),
                        success:function(response){
                            console.log(response);
                        }
                    })
               });
             })
        </script>  
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Resolvido! Juntei as duas respostas e resolvei meu problema por aqui. Muito Obrigado viu Alexandre. Um dia vou ser a pessoa que responde aos iniciantes se Deus quiser. Obrigado e boa semana!

Comment: Pq o ideal seria usar Ajax? Não entendi.

Answer (score 3):

O `window.location.href` apenas redireciona a página, não envia o fomulário. O ideal seria colocar o botão dentro do `form`, mas se quer chamar uma função pra isso, pode submeter o formulário com o método `submit()`:

```
function salvar() {
   document.forms[0].submit();
}
```

Pode remover o `type="submit"` do botão porque não faz diferença se está usando o evento `onclick`:

```
<button onclick="salvar()">Salvar</button>
```

Comment: Muito Bom. Obrigado. Poucas pessoas querem ajudar os iniciantes como eu, poucos tem paciência com perguntas simples, mas para nós é uma resposta como a sua é de grande valia.Resolvido!